# Linux mint 17.2 : How can i reduce cpu usage?

Tags: linux-mint, cpu-usage

I've been using linux mint for month with no problems. Today, when I opened my laptop I noticed a huge CPU usage, although no program was running.

My laptop is a Lenovo z500 core i5, 4gb ram. The 4 cores usage according to system monitor were `49%,49%,50%,45%` cinnamon take between 80 and 110 from cpu

Answer (score 1):

do a 'top' command and see whats using the most CPU and if possible kill the task

Comment: no it's not possible as i mention before cinnamon now i solve the problem by installing mate desktop